# Check data exist before saving in coredata -Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

While saving the data am checking whether the data is already exist or not in the entity. Problem here is the above method is not working as expected, when I run the app for very first time it's showing data is already exist. Please check the below code and shed some light. Thanks.

```
func someEntityExists(id: String, entityName: String, type : String, fieldName : String) -> Bool {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: entityName)
    if type == "String"{
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(fieldName) == %@", id)
    }else{
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(fieldName) == %d", id)

    }

    var results: [NSManagedObject] = []

    do {
        results = try self.persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    }
    catch {
        print("error executing fetch request: \(error)")
    }

    return results.count > 0
}
```

Below is the code where am calling this function to save the user information.

```
  func saveUserInfo(detail:[String:Any])-> Bool
{
    let context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext
    var isSave : Bool = false
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: context)
    let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    newUser.setValue(detail["id"], forKey: "id")
    newUser.setValue(detail["api_token"], forKey: "api_token")
    newUser.setValue(detail["username"], forKey: "username")
    newUser.setValue(detail["email"], forKey: "email")
    if let category = detail["firstname"] as? String {
        newUser.setValue(detail["firstname"], forKey: "firstname")
    }
    if let category = detail["middlename"] as? String {
        newUser.setValue(detail["middlename"], forKey: "middlename")
    }
    if let category = detail["lastname"] as? String {
        newUser.setValue(detail["lastname"], forKey: "lastname")
    }

    do {

        let isExist = someEntityExists(id: newUser.value(forKey:        "email") as! String , entityName: "User", type: "String", fieldName: "email")
        if isExist == true {
            // don't save anything
            print("Data is already present  ")
        }else{
        try context.save()
        isSave  = true
        }
    } catch {

        print("Failed saving")
        isSave  = false
    }



    return isSave

}
```

Comment: can you share the data which you are getting in results array?

Comment: Btw, `id` has type `String`, so you have to use the `%@` format, even if that string represents an integer.

Comment: @SatishMavani [<User: 0x6000002890b0> (entity: User; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://94325AAF-F09A-45BA-B6C8-4343F92DA3EC/Representative/p1> ; data: {
    "api_token" = "";
    email = "john@solutions.com";
    id = nil;
    lastname = nil;
    middlename = nil;
    "profile_id" = nil;
    username = "john@solutions.com";
})] am checking with email field.

Comment: @MartinR am checking with string field only. Yes it contains matching items. But how come it will match if I run the app for very first time?

Comment: Yep. Tried after deleting.

Comment: Updated to full code. Please have a look.

Comment: That looks as if you create (and save) a new User object *before* checking if a user with the same mail address already exists.

Answer (score 1):

First you create a User object in your managed context before calling `someEntityExists` so most likely this object will be included in the fetch even if it hasn't been saved yet.

Call `someEntityExists` before even creating a new user entity to see if you should proceed or not

```
func saveUserInfo(detail:[String:Any])-> Bool {
    if someEntityExists(id: detail["email"] , entityName: "User", type: "String", fieldName: "email") {
        print("Data is already present")
         return false
    }
    //else create and save new user
}
```

Comment: By default, a fetch request includes pending (unsaved) changes. Just not saving will probably not help.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  oops. That's a typo. I removed it. Still same issue.

Comment: @Mac_Play, Like MartinR pointed out, it is enough to create an object for it to be included in the fetch. Look at my code for a solution that should work.

Comment: I have updated the text to avoid any confusion (hopefully :))

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It's working as expected now. Thanks both.